# Usage of emancipation for purposes other than political or relating to a person

Tags: word-usage

The dictionary says

> noun the fact or process of being set free from legal, social, or
>   political restrictions; liberation. "the emancipation of feminist
>   ideas" the freeing of someone from slavery. "the early struggle for
>   emancipation from slavery"

My question is, is it appropriate to use the word in a context other than that, eg. Emancipation from fossil fuel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, for dramatic effect

Emancipation is a pretty emotionally charged noun (or verb, if used in that way). Applying it in atypical ways can add dramatic emphasis to a point you are trying to make.

Because this usage is so stylized, you'd use it once but not rely on it or you'd "water down" the significance.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. By 'water down' you mean dilute or undermine the significance of the word, or something else?

Comment: @Vai correct. Sorry, I should have used a different phase.